# How to link a pre-installed application to the Android Market?

Tags: android, installation, rom

I just got a great news today, my own application will be included on all the phone of the brand "X" in my little country (Belgium)

I got so excited when I am looking at the phones in the shops and I can see my application by default.

Unfortunately, the brand "X" is noobie and seem unable to link my app to the Market, so the users cannot be aware that there is an upgrade in the Android Market.

they just ask me by email

> Do you know how to link apps to the market to get the update
>   automatic?

I know that I don't work for this company and they will get benefit with this information, but have you got an Idea on how to achieve this?

Thank a lot.

**Edit:**
Seem that the app installed in system/app does not automatically get the Market link , but app installed in data/app well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that if an app has the same app name (the internal app name that's a package name) and digital signer as an app in the market, the market will show updates for the app even if the app was not originally installed through the market.

Comment: Yes that's correct, as long as the version is higher and the package name is the same.

Comment: It seem that app in system/app does not update even if they have the same package name.